# Bug with Alt.js and react. State is not kept

Tags: reactjs, flux, alt.js

I'm using this class to display and filter a list. This class also trigger a search.

My problem is it seems that the setState function is not immediate.

```
FriendActions.getSearchList(this.state.search);
```

If I comment this actions. The console.log will print the state as is it should be.
If no the 'search' state will "disappear".

I think maybe a change event is fire before the state is changed. But i have really no clue.

I hope I've made myself clear. If not feel free to ask me more information.

```
onSearch(event){
    this.setState({search: event.target.value});
    if (this.state.search !== '')


      FriendActions.getSearchList(this.state.search);
  }



 class FriendList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = FriendStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.filterByUsername = this.filterByUsername.bind(this);

    // limit this function every 200 ms
    this.onSearch = debounce(this.onSearch, 200);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    FriendStore.listen(this.onChange);
    FriendActions.getFriendsList();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    FriendStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
  }

  onChange(state) {
    console.log(state);
    this.setState(state);
  }

  onSearch(event){
    this.setState({search: event.target.value});
    if (this.state.search !== '')
      FriendActions.getSearchList(this.state.search);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your logic. Something like this should work:

```
onSearch(event){
  var search = event.target.value;

  if (search !== '') {
    FriendActions.getSearchList(search);
  }

  this.setState({search: search}); // w/ ES6: this.setState({search});
}
```

You are correct that `setState` is not immediate. The reason is that you can have many `setState` calls in your code. React will run `render` on a `setState`. For performance reasons it waits until all `setState` calls are done then renders.

Alternative solution (not recommended):
Set your state manually

```
this.state = 'whatever';
```

and update yourself

```
this.forceUpdate();
```